# Cómo limitar registros agrupados por columnas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Estoy intentando implementar una consulta en la que como máximo pueda tener 4 empresas para la misma fecha y el mismo intervalo horario (estas no han de ser distintas). El problema es que la consulta no muestra lo que se espera. Es decir, en la lista de abajo, en vez de las 5 primeras filas, deberían ser 4, pues ya se habría superado el límite. ¿Cómo podría hacer la consulta?

**Lista completa**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Consulta**

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM entregas 
        JOIN intervaloshorarios on entregas.idIntervaloHorario= intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario
        GROUP BY entregas.fechaCita, intervaloshorarios.intervaloHorario <= 4
        ORDER BY entregas.fechaCita asc
    ;');
```

**Lista después de la consulta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no me queda claro porque dices que "NO han de ser distintas", si justamente lo son.

Comment: Me explico: quisiera que, ya sea la misma empresa o no, el número de registros que se inserten que coincidan a la misma fecha y en el mismo intervalo queden limitados a 4, pero aún no he conseguido que me salga eso, por lo que estoy intentando mostrar sólo esos 4 registros. (No importa que la misma empresa quiera meter 4 veces el mismo registro, el caso es limitar eso o que salga a modo de consulta)

Comment: He intentado `$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * 
             FROM (
             SELECT fechaCita, intervaloHorario, COUNT(*) total
             FROM entregas, intervaloshorarios
             WHERE entregas.idCarga = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario
             GROUP BY entregas.fechaCita, intervaloshorarios.intervaloHorario
             ) as num
             WHERE num.total > 3
             ORDER BY num.fechaCita, num.intervaloHorario            
        ;');`

Pero da 0

Answer (score 0):

En MySql tendras que seleccionar la consulta y limitarla a los 4 primeros registros

```
 SELECT * FROM entregas order by empresa desc limit 4
```

En cambio en sql es tan simple como:

```
SELECT top 4 * FROM entregas
```